# how do you do pattern matching is Standard ML?

Tags: sml

I want to write the following procedure using pattern matching:

```
fun sub1 ns = if null ns then []
          else (hd ns) :: (sub1 (tl ns));
```

Where `null`, `hd`, and `tl` are:

```
fun null [] = true
  | null (_::_) = false;

fun hd (x::_) = x;

fun tl (_::xs) = xs;
```

So far I have tried this:

```
fun sub1.2 [] = []
  | sub1.2 (n::ns) = n :: sub1.2 ns;
```

The above does not work. I get the following syntax errors:

```
2.1.sml:6.10 Error: syntax error: inserting  ASTERISK
2.1.sml:7.10 Error: syntax error: inserting  ASTERISK
2.1.sml:7.33 Error: syntax error: inserting  EQUALOP
```

So again, how do you write `sub1` using pattern matching? Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it doesn't work?

Comment: @ScottHunter I added the syntax errors I am getting.

Comment: Try removing/replacing the decimal point in the function name.

Comment: @ScottHunter thank you; that worked!

Answer (score 1):

Decimal points aren't allowed in names; you'll have to remove or replace them.

Answer (score 0):

Since you managed to find a solution, try and see if you can rewrite the following using pattern matching:

```
fun merge (xs, ys) =
    if null xs orelse null ys
    then []
    else (hd xs, hd ys) :: merge (tl xs, tl ys)

val example = merge ([1,2,3], [4,5,6])  (* [(1,4), (2,5), (3,6)] *)
```

You may need more than one base case, but they'd probably look very similar.